# Scraping Data from bitcoincharts

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Background: Python 2.7 is my first coding language with no other code/tech experience. I would rate myself as a beginner in python.

Problem: I am trying to scrape the raw data off bitcoincharts (and store them in a csv) automatically at a fixed interval. Would scrapy or BeautifulSoup be a better use case here, bearing in mind the learning curve I would have to put myself through?

URL (I want to scrape the data table under the "Load raw data"):
http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/itbitUSD#rg60zig12-hourzczsg2015-02-03zeg2015-04-04ztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the raw data that you want is coming from an ajax request send to

http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/chart.json?m=itbitUSD&SubmitButton=Draw&r=60&i=12-hour&c=1&s=2015-02-03&e=2015-04-04&Prev=&Next=&t=S&b=&a1=&m1=10&a2=&m2=25&x=0&i1=&i2=&i3=&i4=&v=1&cv=0&ps=0&l=0&p=0&

and the data is like:
`[[1422835200, 226.160000000000, 232.330000000000, 223.450000000000, 225.834600000000, 288.974600000000, 65610.792992280000, 227.046920360060], [1422878400, 228.790000000000, 243.900000000000, 223.480000000000, 237.687800000000, 1119.126000000000, 255111.532814370000, 227.956041423727], [1422921600, 237.490000000000, 246.760000000000, 236.320000000000, 242.580000000000, 414.730800000000, 99174.059876450000, 239.128755029649]...]` 
where each list in the main list represent a row.

For extracting data from this url you just need python requests module,  because that data is just as pure text. There is no html tag to separate them. Scrapy and BeautifulSoup deals with html. For dealing with text we need python script.
The code will be like this

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/chart.json?m=itbitUSD&SubmitButton=Draw&r=60&i=12-hour&c=1&s=2015-02-03&e=2015-04-04&Prev=&Next=&t=S&b=&a1=&m1=10&a2=&m2=25&x=0&i1=&i2=&i3=&i4=&v=1&cv=0&ps=0&l=0&p=0&'
data = json.loads(requests.get(url).content)
```